# PHP - Create a folder and put a file in it

Tags: php

I need to put a file in a folder named after the current date `(Ex : folderbefore/2017-11-15/mynewfile.sql)`.

I tried :

- change **folderbefore** to 777 in the server (I know it's not good, but I tried it and anyway it doesn't work)
- add www-data to the owner group of **folderbefore**
- set the umask to 0 before creating the folder :

  ```
  $old = umask(0);
  $directory_was_created = mkdir($path, 0777);
  umask($old);
  ```
- I tried adding chmod after to change the permission

  ```
  $old = umask(0);
  $directory_was_created = mkdir($path, 0777);
  chmod($path, 0777);
  umask($old);
  ```

I'm always getting a folder with 775 permissions and no right to write in this newly created folder (tried with file_put_content who gives me FALSE and fopen who's throwing an error).

What am I missing ?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? Are you sure it's permissions?

Comment: not sure, but the folder is created with 775 by the code and when I try chmod 777 on the created folder in the linux console and re-run the code, the file is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem right after I posted the question.

I'm working on a test server on a vagrant machine. In order to give my computer access to **folderbefore**, I needed to add this in my Vagrantfile and restart the machine :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "path/to/folderbefore", "path/to/folderbefore/on/my/computer", id: "unique-id-for-this-folder",
owner: "vagrant",
group: "vagrant",
mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$directory_was_created = mkdir($path, 0777);
```

Needs to be

```
$directory_was_created = mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

If you want to create nested directories within the newly created directory